# How to take a thumbnail from video by using PHP without ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

In my server, shell_exec and exec functions are disable. That is why, I need another solution may be using HTML5 and javascript. Please give me some suggestions. If anyone want to help by giving codes, please provide workable codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client-side you can do it with a HTML5 `canvas`.

HTML:

```
<video>
        <source src="..." type="video/mp4">
</video>
<canvas>
</canvas>
<img id="screenshot" />
```

JavaScript:

```
// draw the image
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);

// set it as img
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('screenshot').src = dataURL;
```

Working example on: [HTML5 Canvas Video Screenshot](http://www.html5multimedia.com/code/ch9/video-canvas-screenshot.html)

[Save canvas as image](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check it.

Comment: is that faster than ffmpeg?